# Removing the date at the end of a string (different date formats)

Tags: python, string, date, format

I am trying to remove the date at the end of strings. The problem I am running into is that the date is formatted in different ways and I cannot seem to find the best way to remove it properly. The code I have so far is below.

```
text1 = "Hi im some text 1.31. dec. 2020"
text2 = "Hi im some text 2.May, 25, 2019"

def remove_date_from_end(initial_text):
    matches = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
               "Nov", "Dec", "dec"]
    for match in matches:
        if match in initial_text[-14:]:
            print("Found Date in Answer")
            initial_text = initial_text.split(match)[0]
            return initial_text
    return initial_text

print(remove_date_from_end(text1))
print(remove_date_from_end(text2))
```

Output:

```
Found Date in Answer
Hi im some text 1.31.
Found Date in Answer
Hi im some text 2.
```

Output for text2 is correct but I can't seem to figure out how to get text1 to show correctly as "Hi im some text 1."

I am not sure if there is a library to handle this possibly. As I know there are a handful of different date formats.

Comment: I think I could probably hack around this with a ton of if statements but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Do you know what all of the date formats you need to handle are?

Comment: is the date always in the last 14 chars of the string?

Comment: Yes, all examples I have run into so far are in the last 14 chars of the string

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex

```py
import json
from re import search, IGNORECASE
from calendar import month_abbr
from datetime import datetime

text1 = "Hi im some text 1.31. dec. 2020"
text2 = "Hi im some text 2.May, 25, 2019"

formats = [
    (
        '{month}, \d{{1,2}}, \d{{4}}',
        '%b, %d, %Y'
    ),
    (
        '\d{{1,2}}\. {month}. \d{{4}}',
        '%d. %b. %Y'
    ),
]


def find_date(text):
    for fmt in formats:
        for x in [fmt[0].format(month=x) for x in month_abbr if x]:
            if (x := search(x, text, IGNORECASE)):
                return {
                    'text': text[:x.start()],
                    'date': datetime.strptime(x.group(0), fmt[1]).date(),
                }

print(find_date(text1))
print(find_date(text2))
```

Comment: Good suggestion. It looks like it is not outputting quite correctly though. I am seeing the output as: 1.31. dec. 2020 and 2.May, 25, 2019. Expected output would be Hi im some text 1. and Hi im some text 2. Looks like regex might be the answer though. It is very foreign to me though.

Comment: @user3571198 - I made a mistake in the regex and included the first number :D